# MYSQL bulk insert - Linux

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am trying to load the text file in MYSQL but I got below error.

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank=@Rank' at line 7

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'F:/keyword/Key_2018-10-06_06-44-09.txt'
                                 INTO TABLE table
                                 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
                                 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
                                 IGNORE 0 LINES
(@dump_date,@Rank)
 SET dump_date=@dump_date,Rank=@Rank;
```

But the above query working in windows server. And same time not working in Linux server .

Comment: Where exactly are you running this command on Linux?

Comment: Yes. This is linux server . But I have execute in via mysql client

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest here that you try executing that command from the command line in a *single* line:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'F:/keyword/Key_2018-10-06_06-44-09.txt' INTO TABLE
table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 0 LINES
(@dump_date,@Rank) SET dump_date=@dump_date,Rank=@Rank;
```

For formatting reasons, I have added newlines above, but don't do that when you run it from the Linux prompt, just use a single line.  Anyway, the text should nicely wrap around when you type it.